# Issue with connecting engine to lichess bot (uci communication)

Tags: engines, uci, lichess

[image]

My engine is responding correctly to the first inputs from the GUI (as above), but when it receives `go movetime 10000` it just crashes and I don't know why. When I test my engine manually in CMD I get the following:

[image]

When I type `go movetime 10000` it outputs `bestmove e2e4` which I think is the correct output. Is lichess expecting something else? I don't understand why it's crashing...